# Python tkinter: hiding a widget after it was place()d

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How to hide a widget (frame) after it's been shown with `.place()`?

For example:

```
lbl = tkinter.Label(root, text="A label")
lbl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
lbl.?() # Hide the label
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is `.place_forget()`:

```
lbl = tkinter.Label(root, text="A label")
lbl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
lbl.place_forget() # Hide the label
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add some notes that I found useful in my case.

I was using an example where the person assigned the label in one line just appending the `.place(x=10,y=20)` on the end. When done this way, trying to use `lbl.place_forget()` failed saying there was no such attribute.

So, creating the label in two lines as shown in this thread is important.

Also, note that place can be either relative (`relx=0.5, rely=0.5`) or absolute (`x=10, y=20`)

To restore the label after forget, you just need to remind `Tkinter` where the label was with `lbl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)`

Comment: "Assigned in one line" is actually trivial. `place(...)` returns `None`, so if you do `lbl = tkinter.Label(...).place(...)` you are effectively doing `lbl = None`.