# Make a button show/hidden with Place Geometry

Tags: python, tkinter

How to make a widget with place geometry showing/hidden?

I know about `grid_forget` or `grid_remove` or `pack_forget`

But I can't seem to find how to show/hide a widget with place geometry.

**Code Example:**

```
import tkinter as tk

def showBtn(e, btn):
    #I want to make btn1 showed

root = tk.Tk()

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="Close")
btn1.place(relx=0.855, rely=0.1, anchor="center")
#I want to make this btn1 hidden when program started

btn2 = tk.Button(root, text="Show")
btn2.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.1, anchor="center")
btn2.bind("Button-1", lambda event, arg=btn1: showBtn(event, arg))

root.mainloop()
```

Sorry if this is duplicated, but I can't find any source for this problem. But please do tag it here if you do find one. :)
Thanks!!

**DUPLICATE WITH:**

[Python tkinter: hiding widget after showing it with place() geometry manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627006/python-tkinter-hiding-widget-after-showing-it-with-place-geometry-manager) (Answered) [For Hiding place, with place_forget]

I still need to show the button.

EDIT: To show after using `place_forget`, you can use `btn.place()` function :)

Comment: have you tried `place_forget`?

Comment: Oh yeah, I found it on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39627006/python-tkinter-hiding-widget-after-showing-it-with-place-geometry-manager. Thanks for the suggestion :)
And sorry for the duplication