# Set tkinter widget with place geometry on top of grid geometry

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to set `btn` on top of `grid labels`

**Code Example:**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Button", width=30, height=10)
btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")

for r in range(10):
    for c in range(10):
        tk.Label(root, text="{}, {}".format(r, c), width=20, height=20).grid(row=r, column=c)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to make `btn` stays on top of `grid labels`, how do I achieve that?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad idea to mix several geometry managers in the same frame... you will run into unimaginable, and unsolvable problems...

However, if you really want to go this road, here is how you could do. (it works on OSX, no guarantees for other systems, or that puppies won't die!)

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

rows, columns = 2, 2
for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(columns):
        tk.Label(root, text="{}, {}".format(r, c), width=20, height=20).grid(row=r, column=c)

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Button", width=30, height=10)
btn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and suggestion about multiple geometry on the same frame, as I'm learning by myself right now :). But is there any way like using `place_forget` to hide a widget? maybe `btn.top = true`?

Comment: I don't understand your question about `place_forget` --> see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489768/make-a-button-show-hidden-with-place-geometry

Comment: No, I mean the Object Oriented style to make widget on top of other widget. For example if we want to hide widget we can use `btn.place_forget()`, to make widget at the top, is there any way that using object oriented style?

Comment: I asked this for this answer tho, sorry if I made it too general. This do helped me answer my question to change the order, Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Better ask a new question.